# Page scrolls up after certain lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have problem when writing around 60 lines [here in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYPgE/5/)

then it start to scroll up !.

what im doing wrong there ? thanks.

I want to always stay scrolled down at bottom.

```
  $chat        = $('#chatarea');
  $submit       = $('#submit');
  $input = $('#text')
  ENTER        = 13;


var addMessage = function(message) {

// create message element
$msg = $('<div>', {class: 'message hidden-message', text: message})
if($input.val().length > 0){
// append element
$chat.append($msg) ;
}
else
{
   return false;}
$msg.hide().removeClass('hidden-message') ;
$msg.slideDown(function(){
    // animate scroll to bottom
    $chat.animate({ scrollTop: $chat.height() })    
});

};
$input.on('keydown', function(e){
if(e.keyCode === 13 && $input.val().length < 1 ){
    return false;
}
});
$input.on('keyup', function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13 && $input.val().length > 1 ) {addMessage($input.val());
$input.val('');
 }
else if(e.keyCode == 13 && $input.val().length == 1){
$input.val('');
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;}else{}
});
$submit.on('click', function(){
 if($input.val().length > 1) {
addMessage($input[0].value);
$input.val('');   
}
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle is working as you want it to or I am missing something.

Comment: no , just try to write around 60 lines and you will see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

`.holder` has a height of `1000px` and `.chatarea` inside it has a height of `90%`, so in your script `$chat.height()` always returns 900, so after 60 lines or so, whenever there's an input it scrolls to `900px` and stays there.

**Solution:**

Use this:

```
$chat.animate({ scrollTop: $chat.prop("scrollHeight") - $chat.height() })
```

Or a faster animation:

```
$chat.animate({ scrollTop: $chat.prop("scrollHeight") - $chat.height() }, 25)
```

Instead of this:

```
$chat.animate({ scrollTop: $chat.height() })
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/MYPgE/8/

Comment: this also scrolls up directly, it doesnt stay down without scrolling up. i want it to dont scroll up only if scroll it by mouse. thanks for effort thought.

Comment: @echo_Me If you type really fast it stays behind but eventually scrolls to the bottom. So just reduce the animation time so it happens quickly, I updated the answer for you.

Comment: you were right , i didnt think about time :) , it works good thanks.

Comment: @echo_Me You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is within $msg.slideDown function, just comment out $chat.animate({ scrollTop: $chat.height() }) and put this code into the $submit.on click function

```
$(function () {
    $("#chatarea").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#chatarea').get(0).scrollHeight}, 1000);});
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MYPgE/6/

Comment: this scrolls up directly . i said i dont want it scroll up , it must stay down , thanks for the effort.